# How am I able to keep my footing on an accelerating platform?

Tags: classical-mechanics

When I'm standing in a train car and the train starts slowing down relatively quickly, I instinctively flex certain muscles in my legs and that helps me keep my footing.

What muscles am I flexing and how does flexing them help me maintain my balance and avoid falling?

Comment: This is not a physics question, it's a biology question

Comment: @Awa http://biology.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this as a physics question. To avoid falling over, you need to keep your center of gravity "over" your feet, where "over" means that the vector sum of gravitational and train acceleration points from your $CG$ down to between your feet. To do this, you lean towards the front of the train so as to move your $CG$ forward in order to counteract the vector acceleration's pointing backward.

Once the train has reached its cruising speed and stopped accelerating, that vector will again be just due to gravity, so you'll straighten up to move your $CG$ back to its usual stable position. When the train approaches the station and starts decelerating, you'll lean towards the rear of the train to compensate, and when the train finally stops moving you'll again straighten up.